# as3 .text not working

Tags: actionscript-3, text

So heres the code Im using:

```
endScreen.scorePrint.text = String(score);
endScreen.distancePrint.text = String(distance);
```

And it doesent show anything, while the very same code in other places in my app works, I tried to embed fonts and stuff but I still get blank space. what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
endScreen is a MovieClip without AS linkage, its manipulated by .visible , scorePrint and distancePrint are a part of that MovieClip.

scorePrint and distancePrint are identical in all but names and are as following:
classic text -> dynamic text

Comment: Give more context, show what endScreen is where is it added to the stage, where is scorePrint and distancePrint declared/created/and added to some DisplayObject, what type are scorePrint distancePrint and endScreen... these things will help also at this same point in code add trace("Score":" + score ) trace("Distance":" + distance )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, the problem was anti-aliasing. I changed from anti-aliasing for readability to device fonts. that fixed both fields.

Thanks for support :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
endScreen.scorePrint.text = "" + score;
```

if not, then does

```
trace("" + score);
```

show anything?